# How to present 'if tr[a] in trs has a tag which name is 'hot'' by python?

Tags: python, html

I'm using python(latest version) and jupyter notebook.
I'm trouble with function(def del_line). I want to make it 'delete line[a,a+3] if tr[a] in trs has a tag which name is 'hot'.' 
I tried but it doesn't delete tr tag with div id = "hot".
What should I change?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
from selenium import webdriver 

url = 'http://oulim.kr' 

driver = webdriver.Chrome('./driver/chromedriver')
driver.get(url)

frames = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('frame')
driver.switch_to.frame(frames[0]) 

html = driver.page_source 
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

the_table = soup.select_one('#divAlba> table:nth-child(3)')
trs = the_table.find_all('tr')

def del_line(line):
    del line[0]
    for a in range(len(line)):
        temp = id in line[a]
        if temp == "hot":
            del line[a,a+3]
    return line

del_line(trs)

driver.close()
```

[in case you can't connect the page, i add part of html tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6Ote.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, filter it out when you get it, instead of fetching it first and then deleting it.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
the_table = doc.selects('div#divAlba>table')[2]
trs = the_table.trs.notContains(['id="hot"','class="bold"','colspan="10"']) # Filter out hot line, title and blank line
for tr in trs:
  print ([td.text for td in tr.tds])
```

Result:

```
['03.05', '목', '노보텔앰버서더.', '1호선 독산역', '뷔페서빙/만18세이상', '07:30~13:30 or 종료시', '1명', '무관', '\\8,600', '']
['03.05', '목', '콘래드서울호텔.', '5,9호선 여의도역', '휘트니스정리정돈/01년생부터/운동화근무', '13:00~22:00', '1명', '무관', '\\8,800', '']
['03.06', '금', '노보텔앰버서더.', '1호선 독산역', '뷔페서빙/만18세이상', '07:30~13:30 or 종료시', '1명', '무관', '\\8,600', '']
['03.06', '금', '콘래드서울호텔.', '5,9호선 여의도역', '휘트니스정리정돈/01년생부터/운동화근무', '13:00~22:00', '1명', '무관', '\\8,800', '']
['03.07', '토', '더채플[청담점]', '7호선 강남구청역', '뷔페서빙/고등학생가능', '10:00~22:00 or 종료시', '5명', '무관', '\\8,590', '']
...
```

Comment: That's perfetlly what I'm finding. Thank you and I have one more question. 'Simplified_scrapy' is released about 6 months ago. How do you find these newly released libraries?

Comment: I found it by accident. It feels simple and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the line `if temp == "hot":` is always going to be False. This is because you are assigning a boolean value to the variable `temp`, not a string.

`line[a] in id` checks for membership: If `line[a]` is found inside the iterable `id` this evaluates to True, else False. And this is what you are assigning to `temp` in the line `temp = line[a] in id`. So the comparison actually looks like `if True == "hot"` or `if False == "hot"`, and of course these conditions will always be False.

I believe you wanted `temp = line[a]`.

Comment: There is my mistake. I had to write `temp=id in line[a]` because <div id="hot"> is in <tr>. Can you reanswer my question?

Comment: That doesn't fix anything. Now I understand why you had `id` there in the first place. You can find the specific tag with `line[a].find('div', {'id': 'hot'})`